# Custom Vue 3 directive updates element's style only after it's been mounted in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, custom-directive

I created a custom Vue 3 directive `v-visibility` to mimic the behavior of the native `v-show` and `v-if` but for the `visibility` CSS property.

```js
app.directive('visibility', (el: HTMLElement, binding: DirectiveBinding<boolean>) => {
    el.style.visibility = binding.value ? 'visible' : 'hidden'
})
```

The problem is that when the binding value is `false`, the element's styles are updated only after it's been mounted and therefore, there is a flash because it is always visible at first.

I tried using the non-shorthand directive syntax to set the style during `created` as well as `beforeMount` but the result was the same.

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to do this with a custom directive?

**Edit:**
Here is a reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-atssfn?file=plugins%2Fv-visibility.ts

**Edit 2**: I should have mentioned that I'm using Nuxt 3 with SSR.

Comment: beforeMount should be ok, consider providing a way to reproduce as this is something that has to be debugged

Comment: @EstusFlask
Hi, I updated the question with a reproduction.

Comment: You have ssr enabled, that's the problem here. It's ok otherwise https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-jmad6e .  The question doesn't mention you use Nuxt in case that's the case for you

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying that! I will update the question.
Is there a way to make it work in Nuxt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. After @EstusFlask mentioned that the problem is with SSR, I checked what the Vue documentation had to say about custom directives & SSR and found out that I need to use the getSSRProps hook.

This is the updated directive (the whole Nuxt plugin), which works fine with SSR:

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.directive('visibility', {
        beforeMount: handleVisibility,
        updated: handleVisibility,
        getSSRProps: (binding) => {
            return {
                style: {
                    visibility: binding.value ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
                },
            }
        },
    })
})

const handleVisibility = (el: HTMLElement, binding: DirectiveBinding<boolean>) => {
    el.style.visibility = binding.value ? 'visible' : 'hidden'
}
```